# Views Bulk Operations (VBO) Clear button gives error after paging and want to clear results

Tags: 8, views

I use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). If I select some rows and 'page' (Ajax) to another page in the Table view. Under 'Selected 1 items in this view' I get a strange error after pressing the Clear button (see screenshot)?[image].

- I use a clean install `(Drupal 8.5.0)` and Bartik theme.
- Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module `version: 8.x-2.2`

Comment: Disable the big pipe module, try again...

Comment: After disabling Big Pipe module, unfortunately still same error...

Comment: @Clive I think it has something to do with `Ajax`. In the view I have to put Ajax on for this module. But the Clear button has problems with it.

Comment: Yes it's definitely a javascript problem, the page you're seeing should be returned and processed by AJAX. For whatever reason, the relevant events aren't being bound to the elements on the page. Check the browser console, there's likely to be one or more javascript errors that are causing it